# Frida Intercept all webview traffic

Tags: android, webview, frida

My goal is to log all the traffic from a Webview of an app. So not only the URL's also the headers, body. And this for all requests so also async javascript requests.

I found an interesting article about this: [article](https://medium.com/@madmuc/intercept-all-network-traffic-in-webkit-on-android-9c56c9262c85).
This is pretty much what I would like to do using Frida.

Using the following script with Frida I was able to log some urls:

```
    var Webview = Java.use("android.webkit.WebView")
    var WebViewClient = Java.use("android.webkit.WebViewClient");

    Webview.loadUrl.overload("java.lang.String").implementation = function(url) {
        this.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);

        console.log("\n[+]Loading URL from: " + url);
        this.loadUrl.overload("java.lang.String").call(this, url);

        }

    }
```

But when I intercepted shouldInterceptRequest nothing was logged.

```
    WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest.implement = function(o, s) {


        send("shouldInterceptRequest()" + o + s);
        send(s.toString());

        this.shouldInterceptRequest(o, s);

    };
```

How could I achieve a full intercept of webview traffic on Android with Frida?

Comment: Are you aware that there are two methods named `shouldInterceptRequest` in `WebViewClient`? So you have to hook both of them and use the `WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest.overload(<define the argument types here>)` to exactly define which method you want to hook https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient

Comment: @Robert You are right, I was unaware of it. Hooking both did also not result in any calls though...

Comment: Does the app implement one of those methods in it's class that derives from `WebViewClient`? If yes then you have to hook this class instead of the base class `WebViewClient` which then only called if the inherited method calls it's super version.

Comment: @Robert Yes indeed the app overrides the function. I hooked onto both to both methods but still no method calls... I hooked also the constructor here and no object of this class were made. Still the overloadurl hook showed that calls were made.

Comment: I would use the working `loadUrl` hook to query the class name of the used WebViewClient implementation (`this.getClassName()`). Then you know what class to hook.

Comment: @Robert Could you explain this a bit more? I added `console.log("classname: " + this.$className)` inside the `loadUrl` hook (`this.getClassName()`did not work). But then it prints: `android.webkit.WebView` which I guess is obvious. I think I do not fully understand your idea

Comment: Typically you don't use `WebViewClient` directly. Instead you derive your own class from it. The loadUrl approach was as idea to identify the used class name but it seems this does not work in your case. You should decompile the APK and extract all class names that extend WebViewClient and write for each class an hook in Frida.

Answer (score 0):

WebViewClient instance needs to be set to webView, my suggestion is to implement it first and then use frida. you will figure it out.

Hope this helpful.[inspector example](https://github.com/agusibrahim/Android-Web-Inspector)